# nuxt не вызывается метод asyncData

Tags: асинхронность, nuxt.js, ssr

```
async asyncData({ store }) {
    console.log('123');
}
```

123 в консоли нет. Почему это может быть?

Comment: а в какую консоль смотрите? Сервера или клиента(браузера)

Comment: и ту и ту консоль смотрю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вернуть значение после вызова asyncData.

Пример:

```
async asyncData({ store }) {
    console.log('123');
    return true;
}
```